# Vibration not work with camera on android?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camerax, vibration

I have scanner fragment, which realized with [CameraX](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax) and [Barcode Scanning](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/barcode-scanning). When barcode is found I want do some vibration for user. But device not vibrate. I use this code

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
        (requireContext().getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE) as? Vibrator)
            ?.vibrate(
                VibrationEffect.createOneShot(200, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE)
            )
    } else {
        (requireContext().getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE) as? Vibrator)
            ?.vibrate(200)
    }
```

and this permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

I add vibration code to some click listener, no reaction when camera work. But if disabling camera initialization, device vibrate on click. Are there any restrictions for vibration?